# How could I tunnel multiple IP address through a Wireguard tunnel?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, tunnel, wireguard

I am new to **Wireguard** and networking in general. I have two servers: one with a /24 IP block and little computing power, and another with lots of computing power but no IPs.

I am unable to reassign the IP addresses to the second server, so I must establish some kind of tunnel. My end goal is for Server 2 to run many Docker containers, each with its own public IP address. I am fine with leaving one IP to retain access to the first server.
Thank you all for your time.

Comment: What you're asking for is basically what a tunnel does in the first place; have you tried setting it up yet? Is the first server also running Linux? Do you know whether the /24 is routed through a specific "primary" address of that server, or whether it's on-link? (In other words, does tcpdump show ARP queries for those addresses?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @user1686 Both servers are running Linux. I have a Wireguard tunnel set up with PiVPN but that’s as far as I’ve gone. Yes, the /24 is routed through a primary address on Server 1.

Comment: It's still unclear to me what you're trying to achieve. That /24 is a publicly routable subnet? What is the current *assumedly private* network on server 2? And I can't see how wireguard would translate requests to server 1 to random docker containers on server 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was easier than I expected.
First off, I installed Wireguard on both servers using [this script](https://github.com/angristan/wireguard-install) to make it easier. Then, I forwarded the needed ports using [this question's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/1067746/port-forwarding-with-wireguard), and surprisingly, all traffic from every IP address (on the desired ports) was rerouted to the Wireguard client.

On the server with the IP addresses, its netplan configuration is completely normal.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networked
  ethernet:
    eno1:
    addresses:
      - 123.123.123.101/24
      - 123.123.123.102/24
      - ... etc
    routes:
      - to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: gateway-ip-address-here
        on-link: true
    nameservers:
      addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
```

And of course, I ran the necessary iptables command: `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.66.66.2` (TCP port 80 in this example, with the client's wireguard IP address 10.66.66.2. You can find the client's wireguard address by running `wg` on the server or client.)

The client did not need a netplan configuration at all. Instead, it needs to allow binding to non-local IPs using the command `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1`.

This is all that was needed in order to tunnel the traffic from all the IP addresses in an IP block (from one port). I have not tested tunneling **all** the traffic, but it shouldn't be difficult at all.